# How do I know which third party dependencies are compatible with Quarkus in native mode?

Tags: java, microservices, quarkus

In the course of development I may need to add third party dependencies to my project. In JVM mode it sure works, but how can I identify which dependencies are incompatible with Quarkus native mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as your dependency is brought via an extension, then it's usage via the extension is known to work in native mode. If you directly pull a dependency outside an extension dependency, then Quarkus can't guarantee this. This does not mean it won't work, just that this cannot be guaranteed.
The best course of action is to discuss the dependency you want to add with the Quarkus community. It's possible, someone else it working on an extension for it.

Comment: I realized that the extensions source codes are not
big, what do these extensions do?

Comment: Sometimes they add substitutions: for example if a class in an upstream (often transitive) dependency somewhere doesn't work on Graal, they provide a class that replaces that class when running in GraalVM that is Graal-friendly.

Comment: There is one paragraph in the doc that explain what extensions do https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions#extension-philosophy